# Sorting Python Dictionary based on Key?

Tags: python, sorting, python-2.7, dictionary

I have created a python dictionary which has keys in this form :

```
11, 10, 00, 01, 20, 21, 31, 30
```

The keys are string

I would like to maintain my dictionary in these sorted order:

```
00, 10, 20, 30, 01, 11, 21, 31
```

This is based on the second value of the key.

I tried this `sorted(dict.items(), key = lambda s: s[1])` and got the keys like:

```
20, 30, 21, 31, 01, 11, 10, 00
```

Can somebody guide me?

Comment: Have you considered using an [OrderedDict](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict)?

Comment: This question is most definitely a duplicate. :) I can't even count how many times I've seen it.

Comment: Hi. `items` returns list of tuples where first item is key and second is value. So if You would like to sort them by keys You should use 

    sorted(dict.items(), key = lambda s: s[0])

but in this case You got keys ascending sorted 

If You would like to sort as in your example

     11, 10, 00, 01, 20, 21, 31, 30

> I would like to maintain my dictionary in these sorted order:

     00, 10, 20, 30, 01, 11, 21, 31 

You should reverse your key in sorted function

     sorted(dict.items(), key = lambda s: ''.join(reversed(s[0])))

Answer (score 4):

You almost had it, but the key is the first item of the tuple:

```
sorted(dict.items(), key=lambda s: s[0])
```

Comment: I'm reading that the "second value of the key" is probably: `s[0][1]`

Comment: @JonClements: Ah, good point. Thanks.

Comment: Also wouldn't hurt to use `key=lambda (key, val): key[1]` just to make it explicit

Comment: @JonClements: I don’t think that’s valid lambda syntax.

Comment: @minitech It's valid syntax. It's just the same as `def myfunc(key, val): return key[1]`

Comment: @JonClements: Ah, not under Python 3.

Comment: @Haidro: No, it’s actually tuple unpacking.

Comment: @minitech Gah. Ignore me then. *flees*

Comment: @Jon It's allowed but it assigns to key the tuple: (lambda function, val). It's not really valid lambda syntax unless you want key to be a tuple of a lambda and a val which is obviously not the case for a sort function keyword argument.

Comment: At this point isn't it about time someone suggested using an `operator.itemgetter` just to get out of the lambda mess? :P

Comment: but it changes to list of tuple instead of keeping it dictionary object!

Comment: @anu: dicts weren’t ordered at the time of writing. In Python 3.7, you can wrap this expression in `dict()` to get a dict again.

Answer (score 0):

A dictionary uses something called hashing and it can't be sorted as such. What you can do is use `dict.keys().sort(key = lambda s: s[1])` and iterate or go on from there.

Comment: This won't do what you expect. The `.sort` method to a list operates on the list in-place, and that list is ephemeral. The next time you get dict.keys() it won't be sorted. It won't be the *same* list.

Comment: yes you are right! `x = dict.keys()` and then `x.sort(...)` Thanks!